# Is there a polynomial expression for the volume of the following set?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Denote the unit $\ell_2$ ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathcal{B}_n$. It is widely kown that for a convex body $\mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the $n$-dimensional volume of the parallel body $\mathcal{K}+\rho\mathcal{B}_n$ ($\rho\ge 0$) is Steiner polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n V_i(\mathcal{K})\kappa_{n-i} \rho^{n-i}$, where $V_i(\mathcal{K})$'s denote intrinsic volumes of $\mathcal{K}$ and $\kappa_n$ is the $n$-dimensional volume of $\mathcal{B}_n$.

Now I am concerned with another (but similar) case. For any point $\mathbf{x}\in \mathcal{K}$, we let $\mathcal{H}_x=\left\{ \mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n:\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\right(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x} \left)=0\right\}$ (i.e., the hyperplane with the normal vector $\frac{\mathbf{x}}{\left\|\mathbf{x} \right\|_2}$ and containing $\mathbf{x}$), and define the set $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{x},\rho)$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{x},\rho)=\left(\rho \mathcal{B}_n+\mathbf{x} \right) ~\bigcap ~\mathcal{H}_{\mathbf{x}} , \text{ if }\mathbf{x}\neq \mathbf{0}_n,
\end{equation}
i.e., an $(n-1)$-dimensional ball centered at $\mathbf{x}$ and embedded in the affine space $\mathcal{H}_{\mathbf{x}}$, and $\mathcal{S}(\mathbf{0}_n,\rho)=\rho \mathcal{B}_n$. Denote the set $\bigcup_{\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{K}}\left( \mathbf{x}+\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbf{x},\rho \right) \right)$
as $\mathcal{A}\left( \mathcal{K},\rho\right)$.

**Qestion:** Is there any polynomial expression for the $n$-dimensional volume $\text{Vol}\left(\mathcal{A}\left( \mathcal{K},\rho\right)\right)$ of $\mathcal{A}\left( \mathcal{K},\rho\right)$? Nontrivial upper bounds and asymptotic results on $\frac{1}{n} \log \text{Vol}\left(\mathcal{A}\left( \mathcal{K},\rho\right)\right)$ are also welcome.

Comment: The volume of $\mathcal{A}\left(\mathcal{B}_n,\rho\right)$ is $(1+\rho^2)^\frac{n}{2}$ for $n\geq2$, so the expression at least won´t be a polynomial.

Comment: @SaúlRodríguezMartín You are of course correct. Any polynomial upper bound is also welcome.